# mcrypt_create_iv выдает каракули

Tags: mcrypt, php

Вот есть такой кусок кода.

```
mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

На выходе получаю что-то подобное

```
L����\���V:#�z���
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить?

Comment: а что ожидали ? вроде нигде не говорится что это должна быть ascii string

Comment: А что Вы хотели получить? `qwerty123` ?

Comment: То есть это корректная строка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. mcrypt_create_iv возвращает результат в двоичном виде, так что чтобы получить ascii string нужно пропустить результат её выполнения через bin2hex.

Comment: bin2hex для соли - плохое решение. Тогда уж лучше рендом хотя бы Прописные+Строчные+Цифры.

Comment: Вообще обычно ваши "каракули" оборачивают в base64 для осмысленного хранения (если не в виде двоичного файла на диске).

Comment: хм...вы понимаете о чём говорите:)? скажите пожалуйста почему bin2hex для соли плохое решение? оно вообще никак не влияет на генерируемую соль, она только конвертирует бинарные данные!

Comment: @SilverIce можно про base64 поподробней?

Comment: @SilverIce первый комментарий не понял, но второй понял. Спасибо.
@zenith с base64 ваша соль в БД будет хранится не в открытом виде, так как base64 кодирует бинарные данные. При получение закодированной соли вы её обратно раскодируете с помощью base64 и получает свою соль. Таким образом злоумышленник получивший соль и хэщ пароля не будет обладать настоящей солью и для нахождение настоящей соли ему нужно будет еще и найти алгоритм по которому соль кодируется. Хотя опять же, если все используют base64 для кодирования то он легко может догадаться в чём дело и получить настоящую соль.